# How can I copy a gtk theme?

Tags: gtk, appearance, themes, metacity

Suppose I am trying some distro (with Gnome) and I like some theme. How can I copy for installation in another computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually GTK themes that installed by package manager stored is `/usr/share/themes`. When you install theme as user, it sets in `.themes` directory in your home.

You can just copy directory with the same name as theme you like into the same directory in another computer (to `/usr/share/themes` if you want use it system-wide, or in `~/.themes`).

Also you can check the index.theme and look for dependencies. For example this picture shows that the themes "elementary", "eHomosapien", "elementary-monochrome" and "Shere_Khan_X" are also needed for "PinguyOS" theme to work well.

[image]

Finally, to change the pointer the following is needed since Ubuntu 10.10:

Edit this file:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme
```

and add the theme you want (see this example:)

[image]

Than restart compiz:

```
compiz --replace
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've edited to include some details.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and
type
  `sudo nautilus` 
 
go to

> /usr/share/themes

You will see some folders with the name of the themes installed.
copy the folder of the theme you were looking for and keep it somewhere else. 

when u want 2 use the same theme on another computer copy the folder. again open terminal and type
`sudo nautilus`
again go to

/usr/share/themes     
and paste it there. then apply the theme using Gnome Tweak Tool